# Probability Involving Senior High School Graduating Class

Tags: probability

I was studying for some quizzes when I was faced with this problem. It goes like this:

> In the senior year of a high school graduating class of $100$ students, $42$ studied Mathematics, $68$ studied Psychology, $54$ studied History, 
>   $22$ studied both Mathematics and History, $25$ studied both Mathematics and Psychology, $7$ studied History but neither Mathematics nor Psychology, 
>   $10$ studied all three subjects, and $8$ did not take any of three. If a student is selected at random, find the probability that
>
> **(a)** a person enrolled in psychology takes all three subjects;
>
> **(b)** a person not taking psychology is taking both history and mathematics.

### My work:

I'm going to try to answer **(a)**.

I guess this particular problem is a conditional probability, because I think that the preceding probabilities will affect the new probabilities. To be specific, I'm looking for the probability that a person enrolled in Psychology takes all three subjects (I denote this as 
$P(Takes\space all\space three\space subjects|Psychology)$) or probability that the person will take all three subjects, given that the person is enrolled in Psychology.

Then, I believe that I can get $P(Takes\space all\space three\space subjects|Psychology)$ by using the equation

$$P(Takes\space all\space three\space subjects|Psychology) = \frac{P(Psychology \cap Takes\space all\space three\space subjects)}{P(Psychology)}$$

The expression $P(Psychology \cap Takes\space all\space three\space subjects)$ means probability that a person choosen is enrolled in Psychology **and** takes all three subjects. I don't have that value though.

The expression $P(Psychology)$ means probability that a person chosen is enrolled in Psychology. I believe that this probability would be $\frac{68}{100}$.

Therefore.....I don't know the answer.

---

I'm going to try to answer **(b)**.

I guess this particular problem is a conditional probability either, because I think that the preceding probabilities will affect the 
new probabilities. To be specific, I'm looking for the probability that a person not enrolled in Psychology is taking both History and Mathematics. 
(I denote this as $P(History \cap Mathematics|\neg Psychology)$)

Now....this expression $P(History \cap Mathematics|\neg Psychology)$, when I'm going to evaluate it, I don't where to start. Perhaps it is wrong all along, but that is the expression that will accurately describe the second problem.

How do you answer the above question?

Comment: I'll use $p,h,m,p^c,h^c,m^c$ to refer to the taking of or not taking of each of the subjects.  You have $P(h\cap m\mid p^c)=\frac{P(h\cap m\cap p^c)}{P(p^c)}$.  Now, note that $P(p^c)=1-P(p)$ and that $P(h\cap m\cap p^c)+P(h\cap m\cap p)=P(h\cap m)$.

Answer (score 3):

I would have commented but I don't have privilege to comment.

For part(a) I agree with your approach. 
$P(\mathrm{Psychology}\cap\mathrm{Takes \;all\; three\; subjects}) = P(\mathrm{Takes\; all\; three\; subjects})$ since you are taking intersection and psychology is included in three subjects. and probability of taking all three subjects is given in question that is $10/100$.

For part(b) 
  $P(\mathrm{History}\cap\mathrm{Mathematics}|\neg\mathrm{Psychology}) = P(\mathrm{History}\cap\mathrm{Mathematics}\cap\neg\mathrm{Psychology})/P(\neg\mathrm{Psychology})$

You can find the probability of $\neg \mathrm{Psychology}$ by simply subtracting probability of psychology from 1. you can also expand the numerator as 
$P(\mathrm{History}\cap\mathrm{Mathematics})P(\neg\mathrm{Psychology}|\mathrm{History}\cap\mathrm{Mathematics})$
now $P(\mathrm{History}\cap\mathrm{Mathematics})$ is given in question that is $22/100$. Out of these $22$ students there are $10$ such students that are enrolled in all three subjects so $22- 10 = 12$ students are such students that are enrolled in maths and history and are not taking psychology.
hence $P(\neg \mathrm{Psychology}|\mathrm{History}\cap\mathrm{Mathematics}) = 12/32$

You can do rest of calculations by yourself by putting the values. Please consider my solution as a comment.

Comment: A useful hint is a good answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Total 100
Maths 42
History 54
Psychology 68
Only History 7 (H-M∩H-M∩P-M∩H∩P)
Both Maths and History 22 (M∩H)
Both Maths and Psychology 25 (M∩P)
None 8
[image: Venn Diagram]

From Diagram

A.  =(H∩P∩M)/P
B.  =(H∩M - H∩P∩M)/P